# How to use SUMIF formula over jagged sum range

Tags: excel-formula

I have problem where the cells I need to sum are in one of two columns. Take this example: I have an ID field over which I will subtotal. Each entry has a v1 value and possibly a v2 value. I need to sum in a way that will take the v1 value, unless the v2 cell is not blank, in which case I would use the v2 value.

One way of doing this is by adding an extra column (I called it choose(v)) that does the conditional `IF` formula to pick the values to sum. Then, I can simply use this extra column as the `sum_range` in a `SUMIF` formula.

[image]

Assuming this data starts in cell A1, my formula for choose(v) would be

`=IF(ISBLANK(C2),B2,C2)`

and then my formula for subtotal would be

`=SUMIF($A:$A,A2,$D:$D)`

Is there a way to accomplish this subtotal without using this extra choose(v) column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"")+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quick and Dirty SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((($C$2:$C$7<>"")*$C$2:$C$7)+(($C$2:$C$7="")*$B$2:$B$7))*($A$2:$A$7=A2))
```

[image]

---

Or if one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER:

```
=SUM(FILTER(CHOOSE(($C$2:$C$7="")+1,$C$2:$C$7,$B$2:$B$7),$A$2:$A$7=A2))
```

[image]